# How do Magento2 translations work?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, inline-translations

There are plain strings i.e. in `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml` and I am wondering how they get translated into other languages.
Also what is the correct way of using translations in PHP code (Blocks, Models etc.) or template files? In Magento 1 it was like `$this->__('asd');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use the translation is `__('text here')`. Simple as that. no `$this` or any other object. Just `__` function.
the fact that you see plain texts in xml files should not be a problem.
the xml files are used by at least one php script. And the php script knows the structure of the xml files including what needs to be translated or not.